# Including some samples without ground truth for training via regularization but not directly in the loss function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

The deep learning literature typically assumes that all training data has ground truth (GT) associated with it, but in the project I'm working on I have a number of (experimental) examples that do not. Yet, I think their inclusion in the training might be very useful due to their contribution in the regularization component of the network to help it be more robust/generalizable. This is mainly because they are extreme yet valid cases and how they behave when fed to the neural network is important information.

I am using Tensorflow 2/Keras. It is a regression problem so let's assume I use an MSE-like loss function.

I wonder what would be an efficient way of zeroing the contribution of these cases in the `my_loss` loss function in `model.compile(loss=my_loss)` yet allowing the contribution of `activity_regularizer` in any layers to be part of the the "global" loss function.

I was thinking of adding a weight vector as input where each sample is flagged if it has GT or not, yet it seems wasteful to compute the loss of these examples to then multiply by zero, although it may be more computationally efficient than filtering them out.

I wonder if anybody else has encountered a similar situation and what kind of solution they implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds more like a semi-supervised learning problem. Further, I don't know whether the idea of "...but they would be excellent in terms of regularization" is really correct or not; however, in terms of implementation it is possible to do.

For example, suppose your model is a binary classifier with a 1-unit sigmoid layer as the output layer. So you could assign an out-of-range label (such as -1) to samples with no labels and then write a custom loss function which ignores them in computation of the loss:

```py
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

define mask_missing_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    # Create a mask of real samples in the batch.
    mask = K.cast_to_floatx(y_true >= 0.0)

    # Compute the loss for each sample in the batch.
    loss = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

    # Zero-out the contribution of samples with no labels.
    return loss * mask

# Use the custom loss for the model.
model.compile(..., loss=mask_missing_binary_crossentropy)
```

Alternatively, a simpler option is to provide sample weights using the `sample_weight` argument of `fit`, i.e. you can use sample weights of zero for the samples with no labels (just provide a dummy label for them) and sample weight of 1 for labeled samples:

```py
model.fit(data, labels, ..., sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

***However, I am not completely sure if sample weights are not accounted for other input-dependent losses such as activity regularization in Keras/TF.***